# How can I make a clear command only for moderators (discord bot)

Tags: discord.js

my clear command works on the server, but everyone can use it, how can i make it only for moderators? Here is my code:

```
case 'clear':
        if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Error please define how many messages you wanna delete, ***Ex: !clear 10*** ')
       message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS");
       message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
            break;
```

Thanks for reading and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if member has a permission. All you need to do is create an IF Statement.

```js
case 'clear':
        if(!args[1]) return message.reply('Error please define how many messages you wanna delete, ***Ex: !clear 10*** ')
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.reply(`You can't use this command.`);
       message.channel.bulkDelete(args[1]);
       break;
```

You can check more about permissions [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions-extended.html#discord-s-permission-system) and [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#base-permissions). Also I highly suggest you to create a command handler.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main ways I would do this, restrict it to a role or restrict it to a permission.

**If the user has a role**

The good things about this are that you don't need to assign permissions, however if you have multiple roles you will need to check multiple times with `&&`

Here is one way:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'admin')) {
    // success code
}
```

However i would do this:

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'admin')) {
    // They don't have permission
    return
}
```

Because it is easier to add multiple roles

```js
if (!message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'admin') && !message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'moderator')) {
    // They don't have permission
    return
}
```

**permission**

The advantages of this are that it's much simpler, their role doesn't matter.

Here is the most simple way

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) {
    // They don't have permission
    return
}
```

and like before you can have multiple permissions

```js
if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES") && !message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    // They don't have permission
    return
}
```